# Selenium + Java | Advice on how to handle waiting and an assert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Hi to whoever might be reading this :P.

I'm doing the automation for a couple new sites we are developing at work and while I have most of it pretty cooked up by now I'm not sure what the best way to handle this particular scenario can be.

The site is a storefront with the usual payment forms to submit credit card payments then a loading screen when the system lets you know if the operation is pending, has been completed or failed. It is done using a responsive framework with a name that sadly eludes me right now (Angular?).

There are 3 lines that I would like some advice on how to handle.

First is waiting until the loading image disappears. This is the HTML line that generates it:

```
<div class="poll-loader-spinner ng-scope" ng-show="editCtrl.pollInfo.status === 'PENDING' || editCtrl.pollInfo.status === 'RETRY'"><div class="hexdots-loader">Loading...</div></div>
```

What I've tried to do here is this:

```
new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 60).until(ExpectedConditions.
    invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".poll-loader-spinner .ng-scope")));
```

But it doesn't seem to be working as expected as it returns control even when the element is still visible on the screen and before the 60 seconds timeout expires. For context when the element is not visible the class 'ng-hide' is added to the above HTML line. Any thoughts?.

==========

The other bit is how to assert/Validate the 2 possible outcomes. These are the HTML lines:

```
<div class="poll-loader ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="editCtrl.pollInfo.status === 'SUCCESS'"><i class="fa fa-check poll-fa-icon"></i><p>Congrats! Your course has been successfully paid for!</p></div>
<div class="poll-loader ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="editCtrl.pollInfo.status === 'ERROR'"><i class="fa fa-times-circle poll-fa-icon"></i><p>I'm sorry, there seems to be an error.</p></div>
```

Whenever one line is visible in the browser the 'ng-hide' class gets removed (and added to the loading bar above). My idea was to assert for the text between the P tags but I'm not sure what the best way to capture that text/the whole element is.

Ideally without using xpath. If there's no other easy/clean way to do it than using XPath I can poke the webdev and see if he can add IDs where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS selector `".poll-loader-spinner .ng-scope"` - basically it would match an element with `ng-scope` class located inside an element having `poll-loader-spinner` class. And, since there is no such element - you have your Expected Condition met right away.

Instead, use just `.poll-loader-spinner` CSS selector.

---

As for your second question, why don't just locate the elements based on `ng-show` and check if they are displayed or not:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.poll-loader[ng-show*=SUCCESS]")).isDisplayed();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.poll-loader[ng-show*=ERROR]")).isDisplayed();
```

`*=` here means "contains".

Answer (score 1):

Delete the space character in the css selector. Use following:

```
".poll-loader-spinner.ng-scope"
```

Comment: FYI, generally speaking, `ng-scope` is not a good choice to be used inside css selectors. Plus, a little bit of explanation alongside with a fix would be good to see here.